# simple MATLAB exercise that I can't solve (basic level loops involved)

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, matrix, while-loop

I have this problem that I'm trying to solve in matlab. So, there is this imaginary factory that produces sutures and they will only be shipped out if the seal on the box meets certain parameters:
1. Seal must be between 150-170 degrees C
2. pressure of seal must be between 60-70 psi
3. the dwell time must be between 2.0 and 2.5 seconds (if you don't know what that means don't worry about it)

So the exercise provides a matrix with 5 columns and 34 rows of data. Each row corresponds to a different suture seal and each column has data about that seal . The only columns that matter are columns 3 4 and 5 because they correspond to the temperature(3) pressure(4) and dwell time(5). Column 1 contains the box number in, and column 2 contains the day of the week it was rejected (1, 2, 3, 4 or 5) if the data about the seal didn't meet the above parameters.  (this matrix is inside the file named suture.mat [that will be relevant in a minute]).

Here is what I am trying to do: display the values of (1-6) and then move to 7 and 8

1) the percent of the boxes rejected due to temperature, 
2) the percent rejected due to pressure, and 
3) the percent rejected due to dwell time. 
 Note: If a specific box is rejected for more than one reason, it should be counted in all 
applicable totals. 
4) the total number of boxes rejected (Remember that a rejected box should appear only 
once in the total, but could appear in more than one rejection category.) 
5) The total number of boxes created for each of the 5 days 
6) The number of boxes in each rejection category for each of the five days

7) create a 2-D bar graph showing the total number of rejected boxes for each of the five days 
8) create a 3-D bar graph showing the total boxes in each category for each of the five days

So far I have only managed to display the values of 1-4 correctly using some for loops with basic if statements inside of them. I can't do the rest and I need some guidance or actual code that would do 5-8. Thanks for your time.

P.S- here is what I have that produces the values (not sure if correctly) of 1-4.

clc
clear

```
load suture.mat;
Temps = suture(1:end,3);
sumT=0;
TBad= Temps(1:end)<150|Temps(1:end)>170 ; %function that sets parameters for which batch gets rejected based on temperature
for iT= 1:1:length(TBad)
    if(TBad(iT)==1)
    sumT=sumT+1;
    end 
end

disp('The percent batches rejected due to temperature')
PercentRejT=(sumT/iT)*100

Pres=suture(1:end,4);
sumP=0;
PBad= Pres(1:end)<60|Pres(1:end)>70 ;%function that sets parameters for which batch gets rejected based on pressure
for iP= 1:1:length(PBad)
    if(PBad(iP)== 1)
    sumP=sumP+1;
    end 
end
 disp('The percent batches rejected due to pressure')
PercentRejP=(sumP/iP)*100

 DwelT=suture(1:end,5);
sumDt=0;
DtBad= DwelT(1:end)<2|DwelT(1:end)>2.5 ;%function that sets parameters for which batch gets rejected based on Dwell time
for iDt= 1:1:length(DtBad)
    if(DtBad(iDt)== 1)
    sumDt=sumDt+1;
    end 
end
disp('The percent batches rejected due to dwell time')
PercentRejDt=(sumDt/iDt)*100

sutsBad= PBad((1:end))== 1|TBad((1:end))==1|DtBad((1:end))==1;
sumTot=0;
 for iTot= 1:1:length(sutsBad)
    if((sutsBad(iTot))== 1)
    sumTot=sumTot+1;
    end 
 end
 disp('The total amount of batches rejected:')
disp(sumTot)
```

Answer (score 1):

For #'s 5 and 6, your matrix's day column is now useful. You can keep using logical arrays to pick out info for each day. Say you want to know Monday's stats: `monday = sutures(:,2) == 1;` will give you a logical array. Then `sutures(monday,3)` would give boxes rejected for temperature on Monday (if 6 boxes were rejected for temperature on Monday, then `size(sutures(monday,3)) = [6 1]`; play around with logical indexing a bit; it's very much worth knowing). So, what you're doing is taking indices for where the 'day' column says it's Monday, and using them to get values in those same rows for other columns. And then you can proceed to pick apart/combine the data as needed.

I've never made 3-D bar graphs, but if you look up the documentation for `bar` you can find info on 2-D graphs, and googling 'matlab 3d bar graph' should take you the rest of the way. Good luck! Let me know if something isn't entirely clear.

You seem to have a good start, already using logical arrays. You can streamline things a bit, though (everything below here focuses on code style). The logical arrays that you call `TBad`, `PBad`, and `DtBad` all have values of 0 or 1. So, instead of looping through to accumulate `sumT`, `sumP`, and `sumDt`, you can get the same answer with just `sumT = sum(TBad);`. With only 34 rows it won't make a big difference, but with a larger data set your loops would really slow you down.

Maybe this is a style choice you made, but you also don't need the `'(1:end)'` indexing - you can do `PBad = Pres<60|Pres>70` (and for the array, `Pres=suture(:,4)`). For `sutsBad`, the `...==1` should also be unnecessary; `sutsBad = TBad | PBad | DtBad` should work since those are already logical arrays.